# Is there a way in jsf/primeface to download a file then change page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

I use primefaces on jsf project. I need to realize two actions on user click :
- download file
- make a back action then change page

I tried several things but nothing is working, either i can download the file or i can make background treatment and change page but not the two actions together

i have tried this piece of code :

```
<p:commandButton id="exportEventLogButton" value="#{msg['avoir.creer']}" ajax="false" title="Export Log" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, null)">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{avoirMB.download()}"/>
</p:commandButton>
<p:remoteCommand name="start" update="@this" action="#{avoirMB.saveAvoirTotalSsRefac}" />
```

Can someone help me to perform actions in the right order or with the rigth code ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by: _"make a back action then change page"_ ? And what do you need in changing the page? I can then write an answer for you

Comment: I have to perform treatment on my object, change state, persist in DB, etc, then change page to display other data from my object. Sorry if i am not clear enought my english is not as smooth as i would like !

Comment: Your english is fine, it is more the order of things and in what step in the actions you need them that is missing in the question and comment. The _"my object, change state, persist in DB,"_ is most likely done before the downloading, so not relevant here. Or do you need that after downloading. That is the relevant part for deciding which of the solutions in the answer fits most. And what is relevant in programming/development in general. Cheers

Comment: In fact downloading and state change, etc... could be perform at the same time,but i would like to perform download first. Once downlad ha started, i can perform other actions.

Comment: Then you can use the solution in the answer with the `window.location`

Comment: try to call the commandbutton for download (ajax=false) from onstart attribute of commandbutton that save and redirect the page

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The implementation of `p:remoteCommand` does not seem to support page redirection when set on the `action=""` attribute. I tried some different variations and it does not seem to like it at all.

The solution is to programmatically redirect when JSF and `p:remoteCommand` calls the action callback (this is tested with Lombok and PrimeFaces 6.2);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
            <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand process="@this"  action="#{downloadBackingBean.onCompleted}" name="stop" />
        <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, stop);" action="#{downloadBackingBean.onStarted}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBackingBean.image}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```
@Data
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DownloadBackingBean {
    private StreamedContent image;

    public void onStarted() {
        System.out.println("download started");
    }

    public void onCompleted() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("download completed");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("newpage");
    }
}
```

This solution will call the first backing bean action when the download button is pressed and redirect to a new page as soon as the download is finished.

Note that this code assumes that `image` is set to something. For the sake of simplicity, I have chosen to omit it here.

### Alternative method using window.location

As discussed in the comments, depending on your requirements, you can also just set `window.location.href` directly upon completion like so,

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" 
    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, function() { window.location.href='newpage';});"
    action="#{downloadBackingBean.onStarted}">
```

This completely removes the need for a `p:remoteCommand` and a `onCompleted` callback on the server side if you don't need it.

Comment: You can achieve this without the `p:remoteCommand` by just setting a `window.location` in the completion of the download if there is no need to do anything in a server side method. That is why I was asking in the comment. If you add this pary in the answer, you get my upvote!

Comment: Yes, that would definetly be another way to go. With that said, `p:remoteCommand` also allows you to do some other bussines logic if required. I guess it all comes down to the requirements of the OP. I'll edit the answer and add it as a secondary option.